# Request failed: forbidden (403) after adding the provided url from Firebase in the callback settings of the Twitter app

Tags: swift, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitterkit

Adding this callback url in the settings, doesn't work with Firebase (doesn't show any user that signed up):
[twitterkit-Consumer_ID://]

Adding this callback url in the settings shows error "forbidden (403)":
https://the-app-name.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

Everything in the info.plist was put correctly: 
consumer id, ....

Everything in App Delegate was put correctly: 
Twitter.sharedInstance.start...,
Twitter.sharedInstance.application...

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Twitter made a change to its api - [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342)

The workaround is to add the following respective callbacks in https://apps.twitter.com

For Android, add twittersdk://

For iOS, add twitterkit-YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY://

Find a Snapshot of this here
[image: Find a Snapshot of this here]

Comment: Error
The client application failed validation: Not a valid callback URL format.
Got this error while adding twitterkit-MY_CONSUMER_KEY:// in twitter console